# std::vector::resize in gcc4.2

Tags: c++, gcc, resize, stdvector

a week ago i upgraded from gcc4.0 to llvm gcc4.2. everything went well except for one thing i have really big trouble to figure out because i am more the audio signal processing kind of guy. so i really hope someone of you could help me. my issue is that the use of ::resize in stl_vector.h has completely changed.

in gcc4.0 the following code compiled fine:

```
std::vector< std::vector<myData> >  mMy;

std::for_each( mMy.begin(), mMy.end(), 
  std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&std::vector<myData>::resize), numMy) );
```

in gcc4.2 it does not compile with error:

no matching function for call to mem_fun_ref ..

i am pretty sure that i do not know how to implement ::resize correctly, could someone tell me what i have to do get this fixed. i am happy if you could show me a correct code example, but hints (books) and keywords that could help me figure this out would also be greatly appreciated ..

thanks a lot for your help ..

kind regards,
bzt

Comment: Could be an issue with includes. `mem_fun_ref` should be in `<functional>` I think.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have

```
#include <functional>
```

in your included.

However it would be easier for you to do this (if you are trying to set the size of all the vectors of myData.

```
std::vector<std::vector<myData > > mMy (size, std::vector(numMy) );
```

Here each vector will of size numMy

Also you do know that gcc 4.2 is still really quite old, if you can I would highly recommend gcc 4.6.

with gcc 4.6 you could do rid of all that mem_func whatever stuff with this:

```
std::for_each( mMy.begin(), mMy.end(), 
    std::bind(std::vector<myData>::resize, std::placeholders::_1, numMy));
```

(although I would still prefer the constructor option if it is required by your use case).

Comment: +1 for using the right constructor to make the bind2nd unnecessary.

Comment: @bames53 any thing to make bind2nd unecessary. I used to think it good  until edge cases like this started popping up. I like functional programming, but it should be more difficult.

Comment: gcc4.6 is no option, i can only have 4.2.4 unfortunately .. what is size in you first example snippet ? i thought size is numMy ? and the vector myData in mMy will be resized by the amount of numMy in my code example with men_fun_ref, right ?

Comment: why such an older version out of interest?  size is how many `vector<myData>` you want in your outer vector. This might be zero if you are adding them by `push_back()`. Note if you are adding them by `push_back()` then ensure you call `reserve()` first or consider using a `std::deque` instead

Comment: current xcode4.3 only has this option of llvm gcc4.2 .. i hope i am not a wiener now because i am using Xcode ;) ...

Comment: @bzt I aren't going to lie I do look down on it. Apple (and by connection Xcode) treat c++ as a second class citizen. I am sure you can update you compiler externally of Xcode.

Comment: @bzt In Xcode you should move to using clang. It's called 'LLVM Compiler 3.1' in the project build settings

Comment: @bames53 yes, but it does not help .. somewhere on the net i found that i should just exchange the stl_vector.h, but then i can use my old computer and work on that .. i prefer the switch to a new cpu, and i need to be on an apple, because the software i am building for ...

Comment: @bzt Yeah, clang still errors on the code, I'm pretty sure because the code is wrong, and newer compilers are stricter than older compilers. But my recommendation to use clang was independent of this issue. Clang is where C++ development on Apple hardware is going. Given your comments I take it you're updating to gcc 4.2 only because Apple has dropped gcc 4.0 support (even though they announced that they were doing that a year or two ago). I believe they've also announced that 4.2 will be going away, so you'll have to do it sooner or later. Besides, clang is a very nice C++ compiler.

Comment: @bames53 clang is a nicer compiler, but c++11 is a nicer language and gcc have a lot more of that implemented right now.

Comment: @bzt yes you could put resize(size_type __new_size) back into stl_vector.h, just copy the existing resize() and change __x to value_type()

Comment: @erik olson really, i am thinking about something like that for days .. but isn't this starting other issues like i can not imagine yet ?

Comment: @111111 clang actually supports quite a lot of C++11. trunk seems to be at about the same level as gcc 4.7: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html Also, IME libc++ has had more of the C++11 libraries (although I think libc++ supports gcc as well)

Comment: gcc 4.6 and clang 3.0 are what is available now, they both have new version coming out soon. Current gcc has lambda and init list. both are important. Trust me I want to use clang over gcc as much as the next guy, but GCC is ahead for C++11 and that language is more important to me than the compiler.

Comment: @erik olson you idea did the trick .. executable now runs fine .. with the llvmgcc42 ..

Comment: @bames53 the Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 also works fine .. is this the clang version you are writing about and shall i use this one ?

Answer (score 0):

mem_fun_ref takes a member function with zero or one argument.

I suspect your code will compile if you were to try that technique with 'reserve' which takes one argument (but doesn't resize.)

resize wants two arguments: a size and an initializer (which has a default value). I guess this is why there is no matching mem_fun_ref template - it is confused by the optional initializer.

Maybe your gcc 4.0 worked around this smoothly, but gcc 4.2 does not?

I tested on a RH5 linux gcc 4.1.2 (no match for mem_fun_ref) and RH6 linux gcc 4.4.5 (does find a match) so maybe you should migrate forward.

Comment: `vector::resize` does have a single argument overload. I'm not sure if C++ says it should be automatically selected or what.

Comment: that is correct, reserve does compile, but won't work in my code because myData hasn't been resized by the amount of numMy .. i am not completely understanding your post, does it mean i can not use resize with men_fun_ref above gcc4.2 anymore ?

Comment: The C++ standard has resize(sz) and resize(sz,T&c) but gcc implements them with only resize(sz,T&c=T()) for gcc > 4.1 . So I don't see how to use mem_fun_ref with resize, sorry.

Comment: @erik olson i am not sure about that, i contacted gnu, and their answer was:

Comment: This change is allowed by the standard, but means that
&vector<myData>::resize is no longer unambiguous.

You can disambiguate the expression by providing a target type to
convert to, so the compiler knows which overload you mean:

typedef void (*resize_type)(std::vector< myData >::size_type);

std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref((resize_type)&std::vector< myData
>::resize), numMyData) );

Comment: and i am trying to figure out since a few hours what exactly i need to do to implement this advice ..

Comment: i think bames53 solution below could be super, but i does not work for all myData types yet ..

Comment: @bzt: I think the typedef workaround is to make the *old* version unambiguous (which was not a problem before) or maybe applies if you edit your stl_vector.h to overload with resize(sz)

Comment: @erik olson ah sorry, i forgot the first part of their answer:

Comment: I am fairly sure the problem is that a single resize member function
with this signature:

void resize(size_type, const T& = T());

was replaced with a pair of overloaded functions with these signatures:

void resize(size_type);
void resize(size_type, const T&);

Answer (score 0):

111111 has the right answer, but I wanted to explain what I think is going on here.

I believe the code is not actually legal, because std::vector::resize is an overloaded function. You have to cast `&std::vector<myData>::resize` in order to select the overload you want:

```
std::for_each( mMy.begin(), mMy.end(), 
  std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(
    reinterpret_cast<void (std::vector<myData>::*)(std::size_t)>(&std::vector<myData>::resize)),
    numMy));
```

Comment: Resize was overloaded in apple gcc 4.00 but not in redhat 4.1.2 or apple gcc 4.2.1.  The mem_fun_ref in gcc 4.1.2 had no problem with overloaded methods - it calls the 1-argument version.

Comment: throws me an error:// _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 402. wrong new expression in [some_] allocator::construct
      void 
      construct(pointer __p, const _Tp& __val) 
      { ::new(__p) _Tp(__val); }